# Computing a contour integral of a function that is not analytic inside the contour

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I'm wondering if there is another way to calculate the contour integral of $\int(\tan(z/2)/(z-1))$ in the square w/ sides $Re(z)=+/-2$, $Im(z)=+/- 2$ other than using the residue theorem. The cauchy integral formula only works if the function, in this case $tan(z/2)$ is analytic inside the contour, which it isn't.

Cheers

Comment: Yes.  Judiciously deform the contour to exclude the singular point.  The integral over this contour is zero.  But the integral can be split into components; one small (almost) closed contour around the singularity, another part that is close in a limiting sense to the original contour, and other parts that cancel one another in a limit.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong on at least two points:

1) $\tan{(z/2)}$ is indeed analytic inside the square.  Its smallest poles are at $z=\pm \pi$.

2) The residue theorem/Cauchy's integral theorem is designed to work with contour integrals with integrands that have poles inside the contour.  As a reminder, with $f$ analytic inside a contour $C$ and $a$ inside $C$:

$$\oint_C dz \frac{f(z)}{z-a} = i 2 \pi f(a) $$

So, that's the easy way of evaluating the integral.  You are of course welcome to do it the hard way if that's what you need to do.